# In a VIM syntax file how can I use a start match in the end match?

Tags: vim, syntax, xquery

In VIM syntax files one can write a syntax region match like this:

```
syn region xqString start=+'+ end=+'+
syn region xqString start=+"+ end=+"+
```

What I want to write instead is

```
syn region xqString start=+(['"])+ end=+\1+
```

where \1 is the match found in start. Any answers on how to do this or if it's not possible?

Comment: My final line looks like `syn region xqString start=+\z(['"]\)+ skip=+\\.+ end=+\z1+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help :syn-ext-match`

> External matches          *:syn-ext-match*
>
> These extra regular expression items are available in region patterns:
>
> ```
>         */\z(* */\z(\)* *E50* *E52*
> \z(\) Marks the sub-expression as "external", meaning that it is can
> be accessed from another pattern match.  Currently only usable
> in defining a syntax region start pattern.
>
>       */\z1* */\z2* */\z3* */\z4* */\z5*
> \z1  ...  \z9     */\z6* */\z7* */\z8* */\z9* *E66* *E67*
> Matches the same string that was matched by the corresponding
> sub-expression in a previous start pattern match.
> ```

So you could do `syn region xqString start=+\z(['"]\)+ skip=+\\.+ end=+\z1+`